# Fourier transform

Tags: definition

Could anyone explain to me how do we change Fourier transform equation from this [[Wiki - look at the top of the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle)]:

$$
\mathcal{F}(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{G}(k)\, e^{-2\pi i k x} \, \mathrm{d} k
$$

to this [[Wiki - check Fourier transform and characteristic function]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Fourier_transform_and_characteristic_function):

$$
\mathcal{F}(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{G}(k) \, e^{ikx} \, \mathrm{d} k
$$

Where did $-2\pi$ go???

Comment: Different authors use different conventions. See e.g. the section about [other conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions) on the same Wikipedia page.

Comment: Here's another site to learn about Fourier transform http://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/

Comment: Would it be ok if i would write down an inverse Fourier transform for my second equation like this: $$\mathcal{G}(k) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}(x) \, e^{-ikx} \, \mathrm{d} x$$

Comment: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/fourier-theorems/

Answer (score 5):

It's a just a difference in preferred units. See:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html

In particular, look at the sentence just before equation (7):

> Note that some authors (especially physicists) prefer to write the transform in terms of angular frequency $\omega=2\pi\nu$ instead of the oscillation frequency $\nu$...

Answer (score 3):

There should be a factor $$\frac{1}{2\pi}$$ in the definition of the Fourrier transform and its inverse (pure matter of convention) so you can have $$ \int dk\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{ikx} = \delta(x)$$.

In your case they absorbed it in the exponential by redefining $$k \rightarrow 2\pi k$$.

Comment: Some say that there should be a factor of $1/\sqrt{2 \pi}$ there and not $1/(2 \pi)$ BUT i think that this is just because some use Fourier transform of a Gaussian and if we want to normalize Gauss function $g(x) = a \exp\left[ - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]$, we need to choose $a = 1/\sqrt{2 \pi}$. This is a bit messed up in my head. Could anyone help me clear this up?

Answer (score 3):

The Fourier inversion theorem says
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt e^{i\omega x} d\omega
\end{eqnarray}
under sufficient assumptions. The conventional way to extract transforms is to write
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathscr{F}f(\omega) & = & \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt \\
\mathscr{F}^{-1}f(t) & = & \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega) e^{i\omega t} d\omega \ .
\end{eqnarray}
Here the constant $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ comes from the coefficients of the Fourier series. The Fourier inversion theorem was developed from Fourier series. We can now make a change of variables $\omega = 2\pi w$ to the outer integral on the right hand side of the Fourier inversion theorem and obain
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-2\pi iwt} dt e^{2\pi iwx} dw \ .
\end{eqnarray}
We can now extract transforms
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathscr{F}f(w) & = & \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-2\pi iwt} dt \\
\mathscr{F}^{-1}f(t) & = & \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(w) e^{2\pi iwt} dw \ .
\end{eqnarray}
We can make an other change of variables $\omega' = -\omega$ to the outer integral in the Fourier inversion theorem to obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{i\omega' t} dt e^{-i\omega' x} d\omega' \ .
\end{eqnarray}
Again we can extract
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathscr{F}f(\omega') & = & \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{i\omega' t} dt \\
\mathscr{F}^{-1}f(t) & = & \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega') e^{-i\omega' t} d\omega' \ .
\end{eqnarray}
This explains the different definition. However, it is recommended to stay within one definition in each text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constant and the transform is still valid. 
Normalization changes.
As Penrose states, if you choose the second form, you can normalize multiplying by (2pi)^-1/2 with the benefit of having a symmetry in the anti-transform (that is the transform and the anti-transform have the same form, the only thing that changes is the integration variable)